# null value in column "email" violates not-null constraint

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express

I got the following error(Error logs) and I found some solution and tried them but none of them is working. it would be great if you can help me with this.

`index.js`:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors');
const adminGate = require('./admin')
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT;
const host = process.env.HOST;

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(cors())

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.send("NODE SERVER IS UP AND RUNNING");
});

// routing
app.post('/create_user', adminGate.createUser);

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.table(`SERVER IS RUNNING ON PORT:${port}!`);
    console.table(`CHECK: http://${host}:${port}`)
});
```

`admin.js`:

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: '##########',
  password: '##########',
  port: 5432,
});

const createUser = (request, response) => {
    const {email, username, password} =  request.params // || request.body none of them is working.

    pool.query('INSERT INTO users(email, username, password) VALUES($1,$2,$3)',[email, username, password], (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }
        response.status(201).json({status: 'success', message: 'User added.'})
    })
}


module.exports ={createUser}
```

`Error logs`:

```
SERVER IS RUNNING ON PORT:3000!
CHECK: http://localhost:3000
/Users/pouya/src/admin.js:26
            throw error
            ^

error: null value in column "email" violates not-null constraint
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/Users/pouya/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:278:15)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/Users/pouya/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/pouya/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/pouya/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:8:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:302:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:278:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:217:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
  length: 184,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '23502',
  detail: 'Failing row contains (null, null, null).',
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: 'public',
  table: 'users',
  column: 'email',
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'execMain.c',
  line: '1974',
  routine: 'ExecConstraints'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the request and response as such because createUser expects these two parameters.

```
app.post('/create_user',(req, res) => {
  adminGate.createUser(req, res);
});
```

In createUser function

```
const {email, username, password} =  request.query
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but it's not working, because it says the `response is not defined`!

Comment: I've edited the answer, try that one. When you make a POST request you get to access the request and response of it. Since you get the email etc from the request in your createUser func, you can pass these request and response.

Comment: `null value in column "email" violates not-null constraint` still get this error!

Comment: have you tried request.query? It seems you've tried request.body. Also, it is worth checking the request object inside the createUser function to see what you get.

Comment: it's working now, please edit the answer and I will do the rest, thank you!

Comment: was it request.query?